# Throttling Google Drive with GPO

Tags: windows-registry, group-policy, google-drive

Is it possible to control the upload rate & download rate of Google Drive via registry or GPO policy?

[image]

[HKEY_CU\software\google\drive] key, does not contain any values for bandwidth settings.

Comment: What registry entries have you found for Google Drive app?